# How to expose InfoPath form to a .NET MVC application

Tags: infopath

Is there possible to expose InfoPath form to a .NET MVC application?Can anyone point me to the right resouces or blog posts.Run out of luck with google.bing.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I can tell you that there are only two ways to serve up an InfoPath form: using the InfoPath client (part of Office Professional Plus) or using InfoPath Form Services (part of SharePoint Enterprise edition).

That said, your only option to serve a form up through a .NET MVC page may be to use an iFrame in the page to embed a server-side form (hosted on SharePoint). You could use jQuery to hide the navigation on SharePoint page so that the form is all that is left on the page and looks to be part of the page where it is embedded.

It's not an ideal solution, but it is do-able.

Comment: Have you got any experiences with putting the SharePoint hosted InfoPath Form in a iframe in a third party app.Any gotha on authentications or just general implementations?

Comment: I have experience showing other SharePoint content in a third-party iFrame that I think would be applicable. Authentication is definitely the biggest issue.  If you are on a LAN and using Windows authentication then no problem.  If not you may have to get creative.  I wish there were a non-SharePoint web viewer for you.  I think it would be a big hit!